# How can i get all days bewteen two dates

Tags: javascript

How can i get all days bewteen two dates. I m trying throw loop, but iterating seconds insead of days.
I also tried to make a new function with paramentar (s, e) but I have error:

-'s' is not modified in this loop

-'e' is not modified in this loop

-Unexpected var, use let or const instead

```
 addEvent() {
  console.log(this.daylist)
  this.daylist = this.getDaysArray(
    new Date(this.startDate),
    new Date(this.endDate)
  )

  const a = {
    date: this.startDate,
    date1: this.endDate,
    date2: this.daylist,
  }


  this.activeDates.push(a)

  this.startDate = ''
  this.endDate = ''
},

getDaysArray(s, e) {
  for (var a = []; s <= e; s.setDate(s.getDate() + 1)) {
    a.push(new Date(s))
    console.log(a)
  }
},
```

**this one is with iterating seconds insead of days  **

```
 addEvent() {
  console.log(this.daylist)

  const ed = new Date(this.endDate)
  const sd = new Date(this.startDate)

  let arr = []

  if (sd <= ed) {
    for (let i = sd; i < ed; i++) {
      if (i === ed) {
        console.log(new Date(i) + 1,)
        break
      }
    }
  } else {
    console.log('try again')
  }

  this.daylist = arr

  const a = {
    date: this.startDate,
    date1: this.endDate,
    date2: this.daylist,
  }

  this.activeDates.push(a)

  this.startDate = ''
  this.endDate = ''
},
```

I m using Vue,Nuxt

Any advice :)

Comment: I solved problem. Thank you guys. Problem was in eslint-config-prettier, i just unistall package and now everything works. :D

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this with a `while` loop

```js
function dateBetweenDates(startDate, endDate){
      const s = new Date(startDate)
      const days = []

      while(s <= endDate) {
        const date = new Date(s) // copy of the date
        days.push(date)
        s.setDate(s.getDate() + 1)
      }
      return days
}

console.log(dateBetweenDates(new Date(2021,1,1), new Date(2021,2,10)))
```

Comment: I have two errors :)

  -'startDate' is not modified in this loop  no-unmodified-loop-condition

   -'endDate' is not modified in this loop    no-unmodified-loop-condition

Comment: I have updated my post, i just made a copy of startDate then it's not modified anymore ;)